# adding thousands of IPs on linux interface

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ip, ipv6

i need to add 50k IPv6 on my server interface, these are used to proxy outgoing traffic.

i tried to use `ip add ... dev eth0` but it takes a lot of time (using a script) to add 10k and even then it starts to get removed (another script shows how many IPs are on the interface)

not only that, `service network restart` takes ~5 minutes to complete.

how can i do this? if i create separated virtual interfaces, would it help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need add all these addresses. The linux kernel supports the IPv6 NAT and you can use the iptables to maps into the whole of block of these addresses without assigning it all to interface.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?